# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'String')

Tags: ios, string, swift

I am trying to pass a pre-appended String as a URL request and I keep getting the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

This error points to the line: `let searchTerm = "http://google.com/#q="+textField.text!`

**ViewController.swift**

```
func textFieldDidUpdate(textField: UITextField) {

    if (textField.text!.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()) != nil) {
        self.webView.hidden = false
        let searchTerm = "http://google.com/#q="+textField.text!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: searchTerm)!)
        self.webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the method parameter name to `func textFieldDidUpdate(sender: UITextField)`, use guard to unwrap your optional textfield text property and add percent escapes also to your string using query allowed character set.

```
func textFieldDidUpdate(sender: UITextField) {
    guard
        let text = sender.text,
        query = text.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()),
        url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com/#q=\(query)")
    else { return }
    webView.hidden = false
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. :) Just out of curiosity, what does the `guard` parameter do in this case?

Comment: It does make sure sender text property it is not nil and if so it unwraps it, then it does make sure appending result of the text it is not nil and again if so it unwraps it. The url the same with the query result interpolated in that string. If any of those 3 lines fail it returns.

Comment: Would you, by chance, mind looking at my [GitHub project](https://github.com/revblaze/WiBlaze/blob/master/WiBlaze/ViewController.swift#L61-L87)? It seems that I have now disabled the basic URL detection using this method. Entering terms such as `http://apple.ca` or `apple.ca` no longer work. :(

Comment: try using Host allowed character set

Comment: It's not so much that I am unable to detect the different, but moreso that once switching from `func textFieldDidUpdate(textField: UITextField)` to `func textFieldDidUpdate(sender: UITextField)`, it just Google's the URL no matter what. **Edit:** And it's simple things like these that always trip me up.

Comment: you can also add a where clause to make sure the string does not have the prefix http://

Comment: I'm already handling most of that [here](https://github.com/revblaze/WiBlaze/blob/master/WiBlaze/Supporting%20Files/NSURL-Extensions.swift). (I'm so sorry if I don't understand, by the way. Recently transitioned from Objective-C to Swift.)

Comment: I was able to do so by switching back to the prior `func`. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: First of all, thank you for all of your help! You have been wonderful with this. Secondly, the edit still Google searches requests such as `http://google.ca` and `google.ca`.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand What you are trying to do. What do you want to happen if the user types http:// or a string with a period?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100910/discussion-between-matt-swift-and-leo-dabus).