# Swift 3 Open Link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, hyperlink

I'm trying to run this function when a button is tapped:

```
@IBAction func openLink(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let link1 = "https://www.google.com/#q="
    let link2 = birdName.text!
    let link3 = link2.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+") //EDIT
    let link4 = link1+link3
    guard
        let query = link4.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://google.com/#q=\(query)")
        else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(url))
}
```

However, the last line is flagged as "cannot call value of non-function type "UIApplication". This syntax is from here, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: That causes the app to crash when the button is pressed "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: Make sure you are using the proper url link. You might have to percent escape  your query string

Comment: I've tried the link on a browser, and the link is good. What is percent escape?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34834294/2303865

Comment: I've edited my code in, could you let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting a "argument labels do not match any available overlords" on UIApplication... line

Comment: try Swift 3 syntax `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`

Comment: BTW Looks like you are adding https://google.com/#q twice to your string. and adding percent to the whole link instead of just the query string

Comment: Okay syntax is updated. I'm getting the same error as before on let url = NSURL(query)

Comment: should be `let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/#q=\(query)")` URL not NSURL

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain what guard does and why this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenURL in iOS10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964264/openurl-in-ios10)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use guard to unwrap the textfield text property, replacing the occurrences, add percent encoding to the result and create an URL from the resulting string:

Try like this:

```
guard
    let text = birdName.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+"),
    let query = text.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/#q=" + query)
else { return }
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate people like you helping people like us with our not so educated bugs and questions. You're literally helping us make a living!