# Swift 3 trying to open URL: shared and open is unavailable?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

This is incredibly frustrating as I knew how to do this in Swift 2. I am building a message app extension and in a class in my footer in a collection view, I am just trying to open a url. Ive looked at every other post I swear but I get the same errors.

I am trying to do this:

```
let url = URL(string: "url here")
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

But I get the errors:
[image]

This should be simple. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39460744/2303865

Comment: Did not work. Above is what I get with that solution

Comment: You have multiple errors. Please limit yourself to 1 problem per post. To fix one of your problems, put a comma after `let text = ""` so that it is `let text = "",`. This looks like a cut and past error. Also images of errors are not helpful; please cut and paste actual text.

Comment: That won't fix it. He needs to move that declaration out of the guard.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Quite possibly but problem 1 is getting the syntax correct and OP is missing a comma.

Comment: @skyguy Is john answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

go this way,

```
let phoneUrl = "tel://45657657" //your url
      if let url = URL(string: phoneUrl){
           if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
            } else {
              // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
       }
```